# Solve a system of differential equations with ODE45 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

I need to solve a system of differential equations in a selected time span, but the equations depend on some variables that change with time. I'm trying to write the function 'odefun' to use in ode45, and when I run the code with the time span and initial conditions it seems to work, but I'm not sure if the code is actually doing what I want.

```
function [dX]=gauss(t,X)
mu_S=1.327*10^11; T=0.06; %constants
a=X(1); e=X(2);
n=sqrt(mu_S/a^3); M=n*t; %need to change with every iteration
[E] = KeplerPicard(M,e,0.5*10^-4);
dX(1)=2/n*sqrt((1+e*cos(E))/(1-e*cos(E)))*T; %da/dt
dX(2)=2*(1-e^2)*cos(E)/(a*n*sqrt(1-e^2*(cos(E))^2))*T; %de/dt
dX=dX(:);
end
```

dX(1) is the derivative of a, which is my X(1), and dX(2) is the derivative of e, X(2).
The function Kepler Picard is defined as follows:

```
function [E] = KeplerPicard(M,e,eps)
E=M;
err=1;
while err>eps
    En=e*sin(E)+M;
    err=abs(En-E);
    E=En;
end
```

I want the variable 'n' to change during time and use the new value 'a+da' (or alternatively 'X(1)+dX(1)'), but I don't know if the code is doing this. It should be noted that this way the code runs without errors, but I don't know if the results are right (if the code sees 'n' as a constant, they're definitely wrong).
Is there something I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to validate the physics it is probably best to ask in the physics forum. // As long as `|e|<1` the fixed point iteration will converge to the unique solution of `E-e*sin(E)=M`, linearly with factor `e` or a little smaller. You would get faster convergence with any of Aitken's delta-squared process, regula falsi in the illinois variant, Newton's method or any other superlinear method. // The last paragraph is not completely clear. `n` depends on `a`, and since `a` changes in time, also `n` will change in time.

Comment: Ok, thank you. My main problem is that with this code one of the variables becomes unrealistically large in a very short time span, but at this point I believe it’s because I chose the wrong function to solve the differential equations.

Comment: Do you have a source where these equations are derived from Kepler laws or Newton gravity?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I used the equations from chapter 7 of these [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.00915.pdf) using a force that has components (Ft,Fn,W)=(T,0,0)